# DataGrid Binding three tabels and autogenerate column

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

i have three MySQL tabels `Student` and `Exame` and `Module` , Student have many exames ana in the one exame there are many modules i want to creat a data grid that i can stock students marks in eatch module the number of module and exames can changes. So far i just need to display the grid i can't even start

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: @Carl i'm new at this i haven't do a nothig so far i just need to display the DataGrid